# A question about flag variety of $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras

We know that the flag variety  $SL(2,\mathbb{C})/B$  which $B$ is Borel subgroup, can be identified with $\mathbb{P^1}$, What can we say about  $SL(n,\mathbb{C})/B$ which $B$ is Borel subgroup of  $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Comment: This is a standard textbook question coming out of the 1950s work of Borel and Chevalley.    See the textbooks on linear algebraic groups, or the more recent book by Fulton-Harris (etc.).   Beyond the linear algebra description in this special case, the interesting point is that the flag variety is *projective* (in the general setting of semisimple or reductive groups over any algebraically closed field).  In the complex setting it's a compact manifold.

Comment: Fulton and Harris discuss this variety and some generalizations in their chapter on homogeneous spaces in their book on Representation Theory.

Comment: When I asked this question, I think I was master student, so if this question was not a research question, I apologize

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variety $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})/B$ is the variety of complete flags in $\mathbb{C}^n$. That is, a point in the variety can be identified with a chain

$$\{0\}=V_0\subset V_1\subset\dotsc\subset V_{n-1}\subset V_n=\mathbb{C}^n$$

such that $\dim{V_i}=i$. This reduces to $\mathbb{P}^1$ in the case $n=2$, as the only non-proscribed datum at each point is the line $V_1\subset\mathbb{C}^2$.

To prove this, generalizing the $n=2$ result, one checks that the "standard" Borel subgroup stabilizes the "standard" flag

$$\{0\}\subset\langle e_1\rangle\subset\langle e_1,e_2\rangle\subset\cdots\subset\mathbb{C}^n$$

where the $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.

To expand a bit more, and give an answer that judging from the comments you might like better, let $P$ be a maximal parabolic subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, so $P$ is proper, contains a Borel, and is maximal with respect to this property. Then $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})/P$ is the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^n$, for some $k$ depending on $P$, which more naturally generalizes $\mathbb{P}^1$ (the Grassmannian of $1$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^2$). What's happening in the $n=2$ case is that $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is so small that the only parabolic subgroup (up to conjugacy) is Borel.

Comment: Matt Pressland, but what about $n>2$. This is my question

Comment: The fact is that the $Stab$ group of one dimensional space $\mathbb{C}e_2$ in $\mathbb{C^2}$ can be considered as Borel subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and so by stablizer theorem for $n=2$ we trivially get $\mathbb{P^1}$ , but what about for $n>2$?

Comment: @HassanJolany I expanded my answer a bit - hopefully it is now clearer that I am addressing the $n>2$ case.

Comment: Normaly we consider such flag, but what about $SL(n,\mathbb{C})/B$?,

Comment: I know that $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})/B$ is Grassmannian $G(k,n)$ of k-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C^n}$, but I am looking for a nice variety, not like this even for $n=3$

Comment: This answer is correct, so if it isn't the nice variety you are looking for, no one can do anything about your disappointment. For $n=3$, this is the variety of pointed lines in the projective plane, which is the same thing as the variety of complete flags in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Ben McKay@, We have this well-known fact that, If $G$ be a semisimple Lie Group,and $K$ be a compact real form of G, which is connected and maximal amongest the compact subgroups of $G$, and also, If $T$ be a maximal analytic tours and $B$ be a Borel sub-Group of $G$, then we have a nice isomorphism $G/B=K/T$, so, if $G=SL(2,C)$ Then $K=SU(n)$, and for $n=2$, $SU(2)=S^3$ and $T=U(1)=S^1$, SO $S^3/S^1=S^2$ , but $\mathbb{P^1}=S^2$, So, for $n=2$, we get the desired result, but It seems for n>2, a little bit is complicate :)

Comment: In fact for general n, we just have $SL(n,\mathbb{C})/B=SU(n,\mathbb{C})/T$which T is maximal "analytic" tours

Comment: @HassanJolany If you want an explicit description in coordinates, see the following MathOverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23426/how-to-compute-the-coordinate-ring-of-flag-variety

Comment: Matt Pressland@ I think the maximal analytic torus for general $n$, is $U(n-1)$, so by this method $SL(n, \mathbb{C})/P =SU(n, \mathbb{C})/U(n-1)=\mathbb{C}P^{n−1}$ ,where $P$ is parabolic subgroup. In fact when we change the Borel group to Parabolic group for this question, then the solution is more simple.

Comment: What do you mean by «the solution is more simple»? The flag variety *is* the variety of flags, as described by Matt, and as soon as $n>2$ this is *not* the same thing as a projective space.

Comment: I understood it to mean that you can get a projective space, but you have to quotient by the right maximal parabolic instead of by a Borel. (I don't know enough to know whether there's any sense in which this parabolic is $U(n-1)$ though).

Comment: Matt Pressland@ In fact If we take the intersection of Borel sub-group and and compact real form of $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$, then we will have $U(n-1)$ in this case. Also we can use of this equality $G(k,n)=\frac{U(n)}{U(n-k)\times U(k)}$ .But your answer is OK for me.Thanks

Comment: Mariano Suárez-Alvarez@ You right.

Comment: How does checking that the standard Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices stabilizing the standard flag suffice to prove that the cosets of $SL(N)$ mod $B$ is indeed a complete flag variety? The coset corresponds to a flag? so if two elements $x,y \in SL(N)$ are such that $xy^{-1} \in B$ then $x$ and $y$ both correspond to the same complete flag? Would you care to share some more details? Thanks

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa This is an instance of the orbit stabiliser theorem. In general, if a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, then choosing a point $x\in X$ with stabiliser $\operatorname{Stab}_G(x)=H$ induces a bijection $G/H\to X$, by $gH\mapsto g\cdot x$. So applying this theorem with $G=\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, $X$ the set of flags and $x$ the standard flag, we get the claimed result by checking that $\operatorname{Stab}_G(x)=B$ is the standard Borel.